# Allowing array of buttons to load audio element once clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a section where I show all uploaded podcasts. If I have only one podcast the current jQuery works, but when more than one is loaded I have problems delegating the event to the extra audio files (can be from 1 - 20).

What can I put as index in below line to account for dynamic number of audio elements?

```
$('#audio-player')[0].play();
```

[image]

This is the code to load the audio file on click:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#play-now-audio-btn').click(function(){
        console.log('hiii');
        $('#audio-player').show('fast',function(){
            $('#play-now-audio-btn').hide(function(){
                $('#audio-player')[0].play(); // Only playing the first audio file, but there are two!
            });
        });
    });
});
```

How do you recommend I `.play()` the extra audio files on click dynamically?

Comment: can you also add the html?

Comment: you are targeting the first one by [0]

Comment: Right, but what would I have to add in the `click()` method in order to target a dynmaic number of audio elements? Targeting first one with `[0]` index won't work when there is two.

Comment: @Liad: The HTMl is very messy, dynamically generated stuff from WordPress. But it basically each episode is housed in it's own container.

Comment: all you audio tag has same id?

Comment: Yes all audio has same ID for now. I know that's not valid but for now I just need them to all work on click. I can change ID's after.

Comment: if you change it to [1] , second audio plays?

Comment: Yes, if I add `[1]` secon audio plays.

Comment: If each episode has it's own container, you can just replace `$('#audio-player')[0].play();` with `this.parent().find('#audio-player').play()` => make sure you are making the `.find()` on the container

Comment: You can see live demo here: https://themxstudio.com/podcasts/the-cmo-suite-ocast-hosted-by-sean-halter/

Comment: @LiadYogev: SO if you see [link](https://themxstudio.com/podcasts/the-cmo-suite-ocast-hosted-by-sean-halter/), container would be `.episode-content-bottom` right? The button (where the even is delegated) is a sibling to audio element.

Comment: Yes, but you can just use my above code, as you have to use `this` so it will find the `#audio-player` that is related to the clicked element.

Comment: @LiadYogev: Yeah, `this` was exactly what I was looking for! Can't believe I forgot about it. Thank you sir!

Comment: No problem bro, I posted it as an answer as it solved your question.

Comment: i got confused with "extra" word in your question , that should be like how can i play the current audio which one I clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$('#audio-player')[0].play()` with `$(this).parent().find('#audio-player')[0].play()`

You have to refer `$(this)` so it will find the `#audio-player` that is related to the clicked element.

Also Replace `$('#play-now-audio-btn')` with `$('.listen-bitton')` as `ID` selector may only select one single element, and you want to bind the `click` event on all buttons.

Your final code will look like this:

```
$('.listen-bitton').click(function(){
  let $playNow = $(this);
  $(this).parent().find('audio').show('fast',function(){
      let $audio = $(this);
      $playNow.hide(function(){
          $audio[0].play()
      });
  });
});
```

Code explained:

First of all, I bind the `click` event to all buttons using `.listen-bitton` selector, then, to find the related `audio` tag, I am referring to the clicked button's parent, and finding it's `audio` child.

Finally, I am hiding the `$playNow` button using the reference I created just in the beginning.

Comment: Although I'm unable to get it to work? Did you try on chrome source maps yourself to test it? Can you help with that part? Also browser is not updating the JS file for some reason, I clear browser cache etc and no changes.

Comment: @HelloWorld I updated the answer, I missed a [0] as `.play()` is a js function and not a jQuery function.

Comment: Damn, still not working. Because using `[0]` as index still only targets the first one. How to account for when there are multiple `#audio-player` elements on the page? If you can figure that part out I will accept. I also get this error in the console: `TypeError: this.parent is not a function` because you're using jQuery method on a JavaScript object.

Comment: @HelloWorld It's not that the problem, if you are trying to make a selector with '#' , you will always select only one element, you must work with classes or you won't able to bind the click event on all `#play-now-audio-btn` buttons

Comment: Yeah but you have to edit `this` to `$(this)` with jQuery wrapper because `this.parent()` won't work.

Comment: So weird, now I get cnosole error: `"TypeError: $(...).parent(...).find(...)[0] is undefined"`

Comment: Alright, I updated the answer with a tested code, let me know if you missed anything I did :)

Comment: Worked perfectly!! Can you explain a little bit? Thanks